# using django-nvd3 for charting, chart not showing

Tags: javascript, python, django, nvd3.js

So i've been trying to get a chart to show in django with django-nvd3. it's basically the same code as in django-nvd3 introduction. But it doesn't show a chart, it only prints the javascript needed to show the chart. I'm hoping someone can point me to the right direction.
I can see that the script is found. Firebug shows the content of `d3.min.js` and `nv.d3.min.js` in the header.
I also tried using jquery just to see if i could get any javascript working, and that worked.

### view

```
def temp_chart_view(request):
    xdata = ["Apple", "Apricot", "avocado"]
    ydata = [10, 20, 30]
    chartdata = {'x': xdata, 'y': ydata}
    charttype = "pieChart"
    chartcontainer = 'piechart_container'
    data = {
        'charttype': charttype,
        'chartdata': chartdata,
        'chartcontainer': chartcontainer,
        'extra': {
            'x_is_date': False,
            'x_axis_format': '',
            'tag_script_js': False,
            'jquery_on_ready': False,
        }
    }
    return render_to_response('temperatures/chart.html', data)
```

### urlpattern

```
url(r'chart/$', views.temp_chart_view, name='chart'),
```

### temperatures/chart.html

```
{% load nvd3_tags %}
<head>
    {% include_chart_jscss %}
    {% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}
</head>
<body>
    <h1>tere</h1>

    {% include_container chartcontainer 400 600 %}
</body>
```

### output HTML(from firebug)

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
        href="/static/nvd3/src/nv.d3.css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/d3/d3.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js">
</head>
<body>
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.pieChart();
        chart.x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value });
        chart.height(450);

        chart.showLegend(true);
        chart.showLabels(true);
        d3.select('#piechart_container svg')
        .datum(data_piechart_container[0].values)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .attr('height', 450)
        .call(chart);

        return chart;
    });
    data_piechart_container=[{"values": [
        {"value": 10, "label": "Apple"}, 
        {"value": 20, "label": "Apricot"}, 
        {"value": 30, "label": "avocado"}
    ], "key": "Serie 1"}];


    <h1>tere</h1>

    <div id="piechart_container">
        <svg style="width:600px;height:400px;"></svg>
    </div>
</body>
```

## Answer by bnjnm(in chart.html)

```
<script>{% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}</script>
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping `{% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}` in a `script` tag? Seems like it would need that to know it is `js` to me

Comment: that did it, thank you. Seems like the django-nvd3 docs are a bit outdated. I did try wrapping the output in a script tag in firebug, but that didn't work too well, anyway all is good now.

Comment: You got it to work? If so, include it as an answer so others can benefit

Comment: i added the answer and made the heading a bit better so it can be found easily.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you found something else that worked. All add it as answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `django-nvd3` is not automatically wrapping the javascript as a `script`.

Try surrounding the `load_chart` template tag in `templates/chart.html` with a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>{% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just update the documentation to rectify this error. django-nvd3 doesn't include tag script by default in order to offer more flexibility where to add the javascript code.

There is an extra settings that can set in order to output the  tag, it's called tag_script_js.

This code should work fine:

```
xdata = ["Apple", "Apricot", "Avocado", "Banana", "Boysenberries", "Blueberries", "Dates", "Grapefruit", "Kiwi", "Lemon"]
ydata = [52, 48, 160, 94, 75, 71, 490, 82, 46, 17]
chartdata = {'x': xdata, 'y': ydata}
charttype = "pieChart"
chartcontainer = 'piechart_container'
data = {
    'charttype': charttype,
    'chartdata': chartdata,
    'chartcontainer': chartcontainer,
    'extra': {
        'x_is_date': False,
        'x_axis_format': '',
        'tag_script_js': True,
        'jquery_on_ready': False,
    }
}
return render_to_response('piechart.html', data)
```

Comment: i understand the problem properly now, but it still exists here: http://django-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#example-how-to-create-a-piechart . You might want to add a comment about this in the code there.

Comment: Just updated the documentation to reflect this options: http://django-nvd3.readthedocs.org/